# Designs for a multi band vertical/collinear antenna for the 1.9 gigahertz range

Tags: antenna, uhf

I'm starting to research building a multi-band antenna in the 1.9 gigahertz range.
I see them offered on wireless routers, and they use them in cellular sites.
Can anyone provide a reference or quick explanation of how they are constructed? Or, is it hype altogether, and the antennae are really only cut for one frequency, but the other frequencies have mediocre SWR?

In the HF band, I've build and used trap dipoles that are multi-band, but I have the feeling that in the SHF range there may be a better/different approach.

Comment: Hi MikeC, and welcome to the Amateur Radio Stack Exchange. As I am not aware of any amateur radio allocation in the immediate vicinity of 1.9 GHz (the closest are 1.3 GHz and 2.4 GHz), this sounds to me like a general radio/antenna construction question. Can you perhaps generalize it so that it is applicable to amateur radio as well? (Also, 1.9 GHz is in the middle of the UHF range, well below the 3-30 GHz SHF range.)

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Yes, I'll reword it for an Amateur-related band and use case. and re-post.

Comment: Please don't *repost* -- please just [edit] your post to make it on topic. I'll put this on hold for the time being; I'll keep an eye on it, and make sure to reopen it once you have made the necessary changes to bring it in line with the site's topic. If I manage to forget, leave a comment here as a reminder once you have edited the question.